The curve to mesh node breaks the relationship between objects (?)
I can move a mesh along a curve generated with geometry node with the "sample index" node. If I want to move a camera at the same time as this mesh, I link the camera to the mesh (parent set -> vertex) and it works. But if I convert the curve with the "curve to mesh" node, the camera no longer moves with the mesh, it returns to its original point, yet the mesh remains in place. Why doesn't this work anymore? Is this a bug or, more likely, there is something I haven't understood. Thanks in advance for your help :-) 


You probably want to put a capture attribute node between the Curve Circle and Sample Index node and and capture the position value there. I'm not positive that'll fix it but that's my first instinct.

@Jakemoyo No, this will not work. The problem is, the camera is parented to a specific vertex of the original cone mesh. As long as you do not use the Curve to Mesh node, the only mesh output of the Geometry Nodes modifier is the unmodified original mesh of the cone with the vertex structure still intact, the curve is not taken into account. But as soon you convert the curve, the joined geometry is treated as a new mesh and the connection to the original parent vertex is lost, that's why the camera does not get a position information anymore.

Then I'd say just set the position of the camera in the same GN tree, rather than setting the vertex parent elsewhere.

I agree with Gordon Brinkmann, my guess is that vertex ID is used for the parenting, which isn't guaranteed to be consistent when adding new geometry. It would be quickly checked with the spreadsheet view.

@Lutzi I thought about something like that, however if the reason would just be the ID, the original cone has 7 vertices i.e. index 0 to 6. Joining the 32-vertex mesh circle makes it 39 vertices or index 0 to 38. Even if 0 to 6 were different vertices then before, the ID would still exist and I would simply expect the camera on some other vertex. But it is at the center, getting no position information from those vertices. That's why I think there is something else which controls the parent/child connection which gets lost somehow, but since I don't know how it works internally... ‍♂️

Thank you for your answers, indeed, there is something broken in the child/parent control apparently. It would be so fun to tie a camera to some crazy procedural animation. The only solution seems to be to duplicate the geometry node tree with only curves to animate the camera. I'm going to report what still looks like a bug. Thanks again to the community.

Thanks for report, this related with the fact that geometry nodes does not support such features like object attaching to geometry.
Blender's answer: "The issue reported here is a request for modified/improved behavior and not a bug in current behavior. Closing as this bug tracker is only for bugs and errors."
